# Fixed width of jqgrid column?

Tags: jqgrid

Is there a way to set a fixed width (max and min) of a jqgrid column?

I've set the width property in the colmodel, but if I resize the grid the columns are adjusting.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One can't define max and min width of the column, but one can make it have a fixed width which will be not changed. You can use the `fixed` option in the colModel.

```js
fixed: true
```

property of the column (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options)).